# Data access in Jmeter using CSV file

Tags: jmeter

I have a .csv data file with data like:
Row-1: A
Row-2: B
Row-3: C

When I run the script with 1 user 3 iterations, it is taking the same value A for all 3 iterations. What do I need to do if I would like to use value A for iteration-1 and value B for iteration-2 & etc.? It did not make any difference between placing the data file inside the thread group or outside the thread group.

Please could someone help?

Thanks,
N

Answer (score 0):

In current form your question cannot be answered comprehensively, the missing bits are:

1. What test element/function do you use for reading the values from the CSV file. The recommended option is [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
2. What [controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers) is used for creating the "iterations"
3. CSV Data Set Config needs to be placed **inside** that controller
4. [Sharing mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) of the CSV Data Set Config needs to be set to "All Threads"

[image]

Comment: Thx, Dimitri. It was picking the right values only. I think the issues was, I used a JSR223 PostProcessor as part of the HTTP request to display the values which was displaying the same values - probably because 'Cache compiled script' option. Only Beanshell assertion displays the correct values.

Comment: Take a look at [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which says about caching: _When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters._. So if you want to output a JMeter Variable value you should use `vars.get('myVar')` instead of `${myVar}`. More information: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)